# Android: Standard image size to be sent by server

Tags: android, performance

I am developing an app in which I have to fetch data from server and show in app.. The problem is the api I am using is sending images of size about 2 mb, and I just want images to be as clear as they fit full screen.

So what size I should ask from my api developer to give me so that it can fit on multiple screens. Or is there any other way out

Comment: For your image to fit for multiple screens, size dose not matter. You need to take care of image resolution like (E.x: 300 * 250). Also you need different image resolutions to fit different screen sizes.

Comment: you mean I have to keep fecthing that 2mb file ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no meaning to send server any api type...

1.I want to say you can set any image size to any phone .

2.Get image from server and get that image by lazy loading which you can get easily by [picasso](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/gridview-tutorial-using-the-picasso-library.html) library now.

3.use scale type on imageview as fixXY

and if you want to really send screen sizes to server than this one is code

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: understand that.. and right now I am using picasso. But the thing is even picasso will resize image on client side, i.e after the image is being downloaded. I am asking if there is any standard size I should ask them to provide me, so that image size can be compressed ?

Comment: picasso is never did this up to we do something in code.
no there is no standard size .

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when you upload the image, upload in full size (Or you can set a maximum size that you prefer) because you do not know what is the resolution for other device/phone.

When you download the image file,send your screen size to server and scaled it at server site before download(which you can use code provided by @Vivek Shah). Then, store at cache. When you need it again, check if it exists at cache, reuse it instead of redownload.